# Springloaded not found with Spring Boot 2 and Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-loaded

I am trying to start with Spring Loaded with my Spring Boot project, but don't know why it does not want to work.
My pom.xml looks like that:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

In IntelliJ Idea it shows springloaded and version on red as NOT FOUND. 
I did not change anything else in the pom.xml. Should I add it somehow differently ?

Comment: Have you declared the correct dependencies in your pom?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it. IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.5 doesn't install to local repository dependencies declared in plugins. So you can do it from built-in Maven tool (View->Tool Windows->Maven Projects) or from a command line, run:

```
mvn install
```

then re-import dependencies using built-in maven tool.